# IDataObject.GetData(string) always returns null

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I try to retrieve and store Windows clipboard, to paste it after, and try to support any type of data (just store it, not read or write).
To test, I try to retrieve Photoshop datas. Here is a part of my code :

```
Clipboard.GetData("Photoshop Layer", false);
```

But it always return a null value (considering that this type of data exists in clipboard at this time. This type is knew thanks to **Clipboard.GetFormats(false);** ).
I've tried with WinForm. With WPF, it returns me an exception : **tymed not valid**

Anyone know how to get access to any type of value with clipboard?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you implemented the ISerializable? Check this out:- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8102/Saving-and-obtaining-custom-objects-to-from-Window

Comment: The problem is that the type "Photoshop Layer" (for example) is not a part of my program, so I cannot make this type serializable.

Comment: I don't find any signature of `Clipboard.GeData()` taking 2 arguments, just this one `Clipboard.GetData(string format)`?

Comment: Sorry, my example was not very explicit.
The real code is :

var data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
data.GetFormats("format", false);
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597426.aspx

In "Return", they explain that it return null if that format is not available, but for me, it exists because of this format is retrieves at runtime by GetFormats(false)

Comment: An idea comes to me : do you think that it possible to store all the DataObject (without using GetData) into a MemoryStream?